# Mule 3.3 expression - ignoring case with flow variable comparison

Tags: java, mule, esb

I would like to compare a flow variable to a literal string and ignore the case of the variable.  For example

```
...
<when expression="#[StringUtils.upperCase(flowVars['officeCode']) == 'REGION1']">
....
```

The error produced is [Error: could not access: StringUtils; in class: null]
[Near : {... Unknown ....}]

I have also tried

```
<when expression="#[regex('[a-zA-Z0-9]+',flowVars['officeCode'],Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE) == 'REGION1']">
```

For the regex comparison, I receive the error "text is not a string"

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first one you need to fully qualify the StringUtils class i.e

```
#[org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.upperCase(.....)]
```

Or you can import the class globally so you can reference it without the full qualifier using:

```
<configuration>
 <expression-language>
 <import class=”org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils” />
 </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

Alternatively you could just equalsIgnoreCase on String:

```
<when expression="#[flowVars['officeCode'].equalsIgnoreCase('REGION1')]">
```

As long as #[flowVars['officeCode'] is in fact a String

Comment: Thanks Ryan,  this worked for me  #[org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.upperCase(.....)]